# GNU-Make test for Unix vs Windows

Tags: windows, shell, unix, gnu-make

What is a GNU-Make test for whether a system is Unix or Windows that works on both Unix and Windows?

For example, if the shell command `foo` always equals `bizz` on unix and `buzz` on windows, I could get this effect with the following in my makefile:

```
IS_UNIX := $(shell foo)

ifeq "$(IS_UNIX)" "bizz"
BUILD_ARCH := UNIX
else
BULID_ARCH := WINNT
endif
```

What command can act as `foo`?

Comment: Have you tried [uname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname)?

Comment: For me on Win-XP, uname is not defined: `'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: It looks like on Windows, you would use `ver` instead of `uname`.  Is there a test to see if a command is defined that is portable from Windows to Unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (`foo` == `ver`):

```
IS_WINNT := $(shell ver)

ifeq "$(IS_WINNT)" ""
BUILD_ARCH := UNIX
else
BULID_ARCH := WINNT
endif
```